# Angular 4 slide in animation

Tags: html, css, angular, css-animations

So i am trying to make a carousel like animation in angular 4 for navigating through form pages but when I trigger the slide animation, instead of sliding  next to each other they get stacked on top i've tried floating div2, making div2 inline, They both slide concurrently which is desired but just ontop of each other where as i want them next to each other.[image]
Heres my code
animations in .ts  file

```
animations: [
trigger('slide', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        transform: 'translateX(100%)',
      }),
      animate(400,
        style({
          transform: 'translateX(0)',
        })
      )
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({}),
      animate(400,
        style({
          transform: 'translateX(-100%)',
        })
      )
    ])
  ])
 ]
```

my html

```
 <div id='container'>
         <div @slide *ngIf='index==0'></div>
         <div @slide *ngIf='index==1'></div>
         ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting the div's in seperate containers
hope it helps

```
<div id='container'>
     <div @slide *ngIf='index==0'></div>
</div>

 <div id='container2'>
     <div @slide *ngIf='index==1'></div>
</div>
```